# Multiplying two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a challenge multiplying two arrays.
this is what i intend doing

```
Array1 ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 )
Array2 ( [0] => 8000.00 [1] => 1234.00 )
```

Every time i multiply this it breaks it down into 4 and returns a result as this

```
Array ( [0] => 16000 [1] => 16000 [2] => 2468 [3] => 2468 )
```

However when i pass single a single data it gets it right.
Here is my code, i'll appreciate any help i can get. Thanks

```
$total = array();
foreach($office_price as $price){
    foreach($office_quantity as $quantity){
        $total[] = $price * $quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "single data"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loop through both arrays, so you get every value twice.

As you know, an array is built up using keys and values.

Use your foreach to that extent:

```
$total = array();
foreach ($office_price as $key=>$price) {
    $total[] = $price * $office_quantity[$key];
}
```

You only need to loop one array, and by using the value from the second array with the same key, you get the proper result.

Comment: What if keys are not always same for both array?

Comment: That is worth mentioning, but the OP is using and multiplying simple indexed-arrays. If he were to introduce other keys, or different lengths, into the arrays then he is likely to encounter other problems that he would also need to resolve.

Comment: Maintaining parallel arrays is not a good idea though, creating a Class to store the values is preferable.

Answer (score 19):

You can give multiple arrays to `array_map`, and it will process the corresponding elements:

```
$total = array_map(function($x, $y) { return $x * $y; },
                   $office_price, $office_quantity);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a= array (2,2);
$b= array(8000,1234);
$total = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++) {
   $total[] = $a[$i] * $b[$i];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array map function it will works

```
$total_hours = array(10, 20, 30);
    $hourly_rate = array(15, 10, 15);    

    $total_pay = array_map(function($hour, $rate) {
        return $hour * $rate;
    }, $total_hours, $hourly_rate);
```

Answer (score 1):

$total_in_array = array_map(function($x, $y) { return $x * $y; }, $office_price, $office_quantity); // This will return array of multiplied numbers
$total = array_sum($total_in_array); // This will return the total

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$total = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($office_price);$i++){
        $total[] = $office_price[$i] * $office_quantity[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To multiply two arrays, you must do it elementwise: no nested loops involved. For example, if you want to get `$total[2]`, then its value is `$office_price[2] * $office_quantity[2]`. Thus the one foreach loop. To loop through keys, use `... as $key => $price`.

```
$office_price = array(10, 100, 1000);
$office_quantity = array(1, 2, 3);

$total = array();
foreach($office_price as $key => $price){
    $total[$key] = $price * $office_quantity[$key];
}

var_dump($total);
// array(3) { [0]=> int(10) [1]=> int(200) [2]=> int(3000) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
function a($a, $b)
{
    $r = [];

    for($i = 0; $i < (count($a)); $i ++)
    {
        $r[] = $a[$i] * $b[$i];
    }

    return $r;
}
```