# PHP array union (linear product)

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any method to get the union of two or more arrays?

example:

```
$array1 = [x1, x2, x3];

$array2 = [y1, y2, y3];

// and the result will be 

$array2 = [x1 y1, x1 y2, x1 y3, x2 y1, x2 y2 ,.....];
```

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do this. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What does x1 y1 mean? Concatenation? Addition?

Comment: what is it multiplicatrion

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18432326/3419997)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP append one array to another (not array\_push or +)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268871/php-append-one-array-to-another-not-array-push-or)

Comment: @Jkhaled Updated my answer and now it should work!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
<?php 

    $array1 = array("x1", "x2", "x3"
    $array2 = array("y1", "y2", "y3");

    $array3 = array();

    // and the result will be   
    //$array3 = [x1 y1, x1 y2, x1 y3, x2 y1, x2 y2 ,.....];


    for($count = 0; $count < count($array1); $count++) {

        for($countArrayTwo = 0; $countArrayTwo < count($array2); $countArrayTwo++)
            $array3[]  = $array1[$count] . " " . $array2[$countArrayTwo];

    }

    print_r($array3);

?>
```

Comment: what is this doing ?

Comment: @danielad it combines both arrays as OP requested